# I cannot sit in 90° on ground

Tags: stretching

When I sit on the ground I cannot sit in 90°

[image]

Instead I only get something like 110°

[image]

I also cannot touch my foots with bend legs.

Are there any special excercises that can help me to get more flexible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have tight hamstrings.
This is the symptom. Lack of strength in muscles is most likely the cause.
The hard part is figuring out which muscles are weak.

I would guess that your core and/or your hamstrings and/or your glutes are weak and that you should strengthen all these.

I would suggest doing planks and Romanian deadlifts (RLD).

The RLDs should be done slowly and with light weight. That way the exercise also work as a "stretch". You could maybe start with an empty bar or even an extra light bar. You should increase weight with time, but slowly.
The key is to get stronger over a full range of motion.

An interesting experiment that you can perform is this:

1. Stand and try to touch your toes. Measure how many cm/inches you are from achieving this.
2. Repeat the movement while [bracing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLHY2-nt-y4) and squeezing your glutes like crazy and re-measure.

I just did this and instantly gained about 5 cm.

This (hopefully) works since you are activating your glutes and abs when bracing, causing the hamstrings to relax. The nervous system detects that your glutes and abs are on the crucial task of protecting the spine and decides to send the hamstrings on a much needed vacation. Now imagine how relaxed your hamstring would be if your abs and glutes were not such slackers. Like most people you probably spend most of your day sitting. While you are sitting those lazy bastards are in fact sleeping.

Continuing my fun (?) analogy:
not only do the abs and glutes become weak from doing little work, they also become really bad at receiving work orders from the brain. When they are later asked to do some work they stare with a blank face and do not understand what you are talking about. This is called poor motor control. Poor motor control of the glutes is sometimes called "glute amnesia" :-).
The solution for this is to tense the glutes and the abs many times during the day.

From the story above it sounds like the hamstrings are working all the time, and therefore should be strong right? Not necessarily. If they are only asked to do light work, and are not given any rest they may still be weak: [Hamstrings - strength & flexibility](http://www.fleetfeethartford.com/sports-medicine/sports-medicine-corner/hamstrings-strength-flexibility)

BTW. I notice you are from Germany. You should really check out the works of Patrick Meinart when it comes to mobility. I am really impressed with the few videos he have put out on Youtube with english subtitles. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58dkMblR9RM) contains several interesting demonstrations showing how mobility and power is controlled by the nervous system.

**References**

[Mobility Myths with Dr. Quinn Henoch | Static Stretching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgL8GkzpNsw)

[Strengthen Your Core and Loosen Your Hamstrings](http://chadwaterbury.com/strengthen-your-core-and-loosen-your-hamstrings/)

[Hamstrings - strength & flexibility](http://www.fleetfeethartford.com/sports-medicine/sports-medicine-corner/hamstrings-strength-flexibility)

[A Better Way to 'Stretch' Your Hamstrings](https://themovementfix.com/better-way-stretch-hamstrings/)

Comment: Thank you for all these resources. I need some time to go through them. I am already doing deadlift and squats with about 70kg. I feel like my core and glutes are fine, but that I have problems with my hamstrings. When I  try to bend to touch my legs, I feel the pain only in the hamstrings. I watched the first 10 minutes from Patrick Meinarts video and I really enjoyed it. I will dig deeper into that. Thanks for your help.